# How to make my PHP session as secure as possible?

Tags: php, security, session

I have a file named **send.php** in which I have a session which carries a randomly generated passkey to the **result.php**. The passkey is renewed on page load. If an intruder tries to bypass **send.php**, an error is shown in **result.php**. The randomly generated key matter because it is a virtual passkey ( not real, it undergoes different levels of changes to help the formation of the real key ), to encrypt as well as decrypt my data in PHP. I am hosting my site at [InfinityFree](http://infinityfree.net), where I am not allowed to make changes in the **php.ini** file, nor I have SSL. So, what could be the best way to save myself from hijacking, since security is the most important point of my site ? Or is there there any other secure way to accomplanish what I want ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Find a host that offers SSL, because without that, there's not much meaningful security from a number of possible attacks.